# C: How do I convert %20 to spaces?

Tags: c, drag-and-drop, gtk

I ran across this program while writing a graphical frontend to the GNU Coreutils `shred` program. When a user drags in a file that has spaces in it, such as `my private data.docx`the GTK+ DND service represents those spaces as `%20`. Using that example i would get (for the filename) `my%20private&20data.docx`. I need to convert those to space characters because I use the `fopen` function from `stdio.h`. `fopen` refuses to open filenames like that because it does not recognize `%20` as a representation for a space.

Comment: Create a copy of the string, replacing the sequence `%hh` with the hex value `hh`.

Comment: One question. what if there's a file with the actual name `my%20private&20data.docx`? What does GTK return then?

Comment: Sorry but SO isn't a free coding service. At SO we can answer question about **your** code but we don't write the code for you.

Comment: That is URL encoding. You should be wary it can be used for other characters as well, with different values.

Comment: The proper thing is to decode the **entire url** correctly. Perhaps you should place a document in `/tmp/foo bar/my private data.docx` then drag that to the area and then present *that entire URL* in the question. How this is written now is hardly useful.

Comment: It would deliver `my%20private&20data.docx`, assuming that the operating system would allow such a filename, which I am very sure Linux does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not replace `%20` with spaces. You decode the URL into a filename, with
[`g_filename_from_uri`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-URI-Functions.html#g-filename-from-uri):

```
gchar *
g_filename_from_uri (const gchar *uri,
                     gchar **hostname,
                     GError **error);
```

and usage therefore

```
gchar *filename = g_filename_from_uri(uri, NULL, NULL);
```

at its simplest.